# Filtering model data

Tags: django, django-models

Code:

```
class JobsManager(models.Manager):
   def get_active_by_category(self, cat, limit):
        import datetime
        from django.db.models import Q
        return self.filter(Q(category__exact=cat), Q(is_activated__exact=True),  expires_at__gt=datetime.datetime.now()).values('id').order_by('-expires_at')[limit:]
```

Even if I provide existed category (cat), and I am sure that I have activated and not expired jobs from this category in database this method always returns empty list.

What I am doing wrong?

Database access in Django is so much annoying

Comment: "I am sure that I have activated and not expired jobs from this category in database" Prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note the [limit:] at the last, did you mean [:limit] ?

Also, Q is not necessary for AND conditions inside one filter, and __exact lookup is used by default. So it could be

```
class JobsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_active_by_category(self, cat, limit):
        import datetime
        return self.filter(category=cat, is_activated=True,  
            expires_at__gt=datetime.datetime.now()).values('id').order_by('-expires_at')[:limit]
```